# Ffmpeg command is not working for firefox in .Net

Tags: .net, angular, firefox, ffmpeg, codec

I am recoridng video in angular and send video to .net Api to process it to load metadata with this command
     `//var ffmpegCommand = $"-i \"{tempFilePath}\" -c copy -map_metadata 0 \"{outputFilePath}\"";`

This is working fine for every browser except Firefox.

I want that my video load metadata for every browser with Ffmpeg
Currently I am using ffmpeg 6.0 version